# How to connect R with a database in PowerBI

Tags: r, powerbi

I am working with employee hours file for work and the files are quite large (over 5 million records). Currently, we have a database in PowerBI that contains the employee hours and then we export it to excel and then upload to R. Yet, is there a way for R to connect with the Power BI database? I have searched online and been unable to find anything.

If anybody could give some insight or resources that would be quite helpful, for our current method is clumsy and time consuming.

I haven't been able to come up with a method to connect R with the Power BI database.

Comment: Power BI is not a database, it's just visualization/analysis software. Is there any reason you cant just import the underlying data directly into R? Of course, if you want to run R within PBI there are [plenty of resources and guides](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=run+r+in+powerbi&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) to do that. Good luck!

Comment: Power BI uses Power Query to connect to data sources. Power BI data sources are documented in the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/ The answer to your question really depends on what database is behind your PowerBI instance. If, for example, your backend data source is an MS SQL database you can easily connect as outlined here: https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/214510788-Setting-up-R-to-connect-to-SQL-Server

Comment: Taking the Posit reference a step further, whether your DB is SQL Server (as above) or PostgreSQL or SQLite or DuckDB or ... many others, https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/ is a good starting point, as are https://dbi.r-dbi.org/ and https://odbc.r-dbi.org/.